# show JasperReport from Java & Struts in PDF/XLS/HTML/etc

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports, struts

I am using struts & java and new to *JasperReports*. I want to show up my report from *Java*. so i want to enter parameters and output format as I want. and when i pres button "Show Report" it will show the report in format that i choose before. can someone give me simple java code to show the report ?

here my information :

```
my connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "root", "dbpass";
my report name = "report1.jasper";
my report path = "D:\report\";
```

Comment: [JasperReports - Sample Reference (version 5.6.1)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend these tutorial for a starter: [JasperReports Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/). And here it is the parameters section: [Reports Parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_parameters.htm)

Comment: I use iReport-5.5.0, is it the same with JasperReports 5.5.0?

Comment: iReport is just a tool for designing JasperReports templates, while the later is the engine itself. iReports uses such an engine to produce reports. So, they are not the same, but iReports does use JasperReports. The fact that you are using a certain version of iReport (5.5.0), could probably mean that you are also using the same version of the engine (JasperReports 5.5.0), but you should check the build configuration to be sure.